I get the error [PIC18] PC=0x0000. $MCLR$ is low. The processor is in reset. [U1] in my simulation
I am making a code in PIC C compiler to turn on and off a LED. However it is not working on my physical board or in the simulation.
Error message is:

[PIC18] PC=0x0000. $MCLR$ is low. The processor is in reset. [U1]


#include <18F4550.h>

#FUSES NOWDT       // Watchdog Timer desactivado
#FUSES HS          // Oscilador de alta velocidad
#FUSES NOPUT       // No usar Power-Up Timer
#FUSES NOLVP       // No habilitar programación de baja tensión
#FUSES NOPROTECT   // Código no protegido contra lectura/escritura
#FUSES BROWNOUT    // Reset por bajo voltaje habilitado
#use delay(clock=20000000) // 20 MHz de velocidad de reloj
#use fast_io(B) // Configuración manual de los puertos


void main() 
{
   set_tris_b(0x00); // Configurar el puerto B como salida
   output_b(0x00);   // Inicializar el puerto B con todos los pines apagados

   while (true) 
   {
      output_bit(PIN_B0, 1); // Encender el LED conectado al pin B0
      delay_ms(1000);        // Esperar 1 segundo
      output_bit(PIN_B0, 0); // Apagar el LED
      delay_ms(1000);        // Esperar 1 segundo
   }
}


You missed a some things:

Where is the power supply for the PIC?
Pull up resistor on MCLR pin?
Current liminting resistor for the LED?
Switch oscillator to internal or use a chrystal
Switch pin B0 to digital with the ADCON1register
...


The error message seems clear: master clear (MCLR, pin 1) needs to be connected to 5V.
If you want to keep MCLR disconnected, consult PIC's datasheet to see how to configure this option in FUSE bits. Additionally, confirm settings for using the internal crystal also in datasheet (I think high speed (HS) option is only for external crystal).
Proteus provides supply voltage to PIC implicitly. But @Mike is
is correct about inserting a resistor between LED and the pin chosen to drive it.
Saludos!
